# C#: While condition on function with out parameter?

Tags: c#

I am working with an API that uses functions that use `out` parameters. I want to use the value in one of these `out` parameters in a while loop. For example:

```
static int counter = 0;

static void getCounterValue(out int val)
{
    val = counter;
    counter++;
}

static void Main()
{
    // Right now, I'm having to do this:
    int checkVal = 0; // I have to figure out an appropriate starting value.
    while (checkVal < 10) 
    {
        getCounterValue(out checkVal);
        Console.WriteLine("Still waiting.");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Done.");
}
```

Is there a simpler syntax to do this? I want something more classic like `while (getCounterValue() < 10)`, but I have to deal with the `out` parameters because it's an API that I can't change.

Comment: Is the return type of the method in your API `void`? (I know it is in your example, but example may not match reality exactly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
do
{
    getCounterValue(out checkVal);
    Console.WriteLine("Still waiting.");
} while (checkVal < 10)
```

Comment: @fdmillion What if the first call to `getCounterValue` outputs 10?  Would you still want to print "Still waiting"?

Comment: `while` and `do-while` are not functionally equivalent -- the latter always has at least one execution.

Comment: @juharr - it is basically the same as the OP's code...there is always one execution. This just removes the first assignment of checkVal.

Comment: The original example outputs “Still waiting” if the first call to `getCounterValue` outputs 10.

Comment: @RufusL  I'm guessing this is just and example and wanted to point out the difference between a `while` loop that would immediately check the value and a `do while` that will always do at least one execution.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do anything directly, the return value of the method call is what `while` will use and that can't be the value you want. If this is causing you problems, you can always wrap the method call:

```
int wrappedGetCounterValue()
{
   int i;
   getCounterValue(out i);
   return i;
}
```

Or with C# 7:

```
int wrappedGetCounterValue()
{
   getCounterValue(out int i);
   return i;
}
```

And use that in your `while` loop.

```
while (wrappedGetCounterValue() < 10)
   ....
```

Comment: Since `i` is an out parameter, it must be delcared but it does not have to be initialized by the caller. Starting with VS 2017, you can declare the parameter in-place: `getCounterValue(out int i);`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the infinite loop with break condition:

```
while (true)
{
   int checkVal;
   getCounterValue(out checkVal);
   if (10 <= checkVal)
      break;

   Console.WriteLine("Still waiting.");
}
```

**Note** the difference between `do..while (checkVal < 10)` option is that you will not output `"Still waiting"` message if first counter value will be greater or equal to 10. You cannot do that with `do..while` loop unless you will duplicate loop break condition `(checkVal < 10)`.

Comment: do-while is the preferred way to go. See Dour High Arch's answer.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I have seen it. Read note in the answer

Comment: Whether my way is preferred or not depends on the answer to @juharr's question.

Comment: What I mean is: there is no point in using a `while (true)` and use a `break` as last statement inside it, when you can write `do { ... } while (checkVal <= 10);`. The logic is the same. `while (true)` is a workaround for an endless loop and can be avoided like this. But I see that you have edited meanwhile and its not the last statement any more. Its ok now.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes agree, the whole point of this answer was option to omit `Still waiting` message on first loop. I have made it clear now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another option (but with the cost of code duplication) is to use `for` loop:

```
int checkVal;
for (getCounterValue(out checkVal); checkVal < 10; getCounterValue(out checkVal))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Still waiting.");
}
Console.WriteLine("Done.");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely hide the `out` functionality you must use a wrapper method. If you care only for "valid" values and the validity is well-defined by the `<10` expression, then you can hide the `<10` expression in that wrapper, and use a `Nullable<int>` in your code. That would be semantically correct.

```
static int counter = 0;

static void getCounterValue(out int val)
{
    val = counter;
    counter++;
}

static Nullable<int> getValidCounterValue()
{
    int outResult;

    getCounterValue(out outResult);

    if (outResult < 10)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        return outResult;
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    Nullable<int> checkVal = new Nullable<int>();

    while (!checkVal.HasValue)
    {
        checkVal = getValidCounterValue();
        Console.WriteLine("Still waiting.");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Done. Valid value is:" + checkVal.Value.ToString());
}
```